# (Re-) Modelling DOM as specific projection JavaScript || jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-traversal

I would like to create a specific projection of the DOM tree, with only some attributes instead of DOM nodes.

Let's say we have this HTML:

```
<div data-foo="bar0">
   <div data-foo="bar1">
      <div>
          <div data-foo="bar2">
          </div>
          <div data-foo="bar3">
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div data-foo="bar4">
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to only get the `data-foo` attributes, but hold the DOM tree's arrangement. ( Every node, that doesn't have `data-foo` attribute shall be ignored. )

I imagine the result of the example above after the harvesting like this:
( As an array / object )

```
someStorageVariableForTheDOMFootPrint["bar0"]
```

shall have two indexes in it, `bar1` and `bar4`.
Going further, `bar1` index shall be an array again, containing two indexes `bar2` and `bar3`. These can all be empty variables, the index, and the array / object structure is important.

No DOM nodes, no context, nothing shall be stored only the data-foo attribute, but in the structure of the DOM tree.

How should I start right?

Comment: The `div` above `bar2` and `bar3` will create a problem. Can that be removed?

Comment: No, actually I wanted to represent, that the DOM tree can be a bit more complex, and there are elements, that shall be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is create an object graph that's a transformation of your DOM object graph, into a result probably looking something like this:

```
{
    "foo": "bar0",
    "children": [
        {
            "foo": "bar1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "foo": "bar2",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "foo": "bar3",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "foo": "bar4",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I got interested, and found it's surprisingly easy to do: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/hemuk/2)

```
function graph(element) {
    var rv, child, $element, index;

    // Wrap the element
    $element = $(element);

    // Our non-DOM equivalent object
    rv = {
        foo: $element.attr("data-foo")
    };

    // Get its children
    rv.children = $element.children().get().map(graph);

    // If any children are missing foo, replace them with their children
    index = 0;
    while (index < rv.children.length) {
        child = rv.children[index];
        if (!child.foo) {
            // No foo, replace the element with its children
            replaceElementWith(rv.children, index, child.children);
            index += child.children.length;
        } else {
            ++index;
        }
    }
    return rv;
}

// Replace the array element at the given position with the elements from
// the given array
function replaceElementWith(array, index, newElements) {
    var args = [index, 1];
    if (newElements.length) {
        args.push.apply(args, newElements);
    }
    array.splice.apply(array, args);
}
```

Comment: Could You, please extend Your aswer with a snippet, how to display the returned object in this clear way?

Comment: @StevenPalinkas: The live example uses `JSON.stringify` on the result and outputs that; you could use a JSON pretty-printer like http://jsonlint.com/ (there's a JS version [here](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint)).